# Cómo mostrar estos resultados del comando cut de linux?

Tags: script, shell

Lo que necesito es mostrar los gid y los nombres de los grupos de forma ordenada, pero hay un problema, a la hora de cortar una determinada columna el orden seria ascendente 1,2,3...

Si yo quisiera mostrar los nombres y sus guid seria asi

`less /etc/group | cut -d ":" -f 1,3 | sort` pero esto no me sirve.

gracias

un saludo

Comment: Podrías, por ejemplo, [edit] e indicar, a partir de un contenido supuesto del archivo, cuál es la salida específica deseada. **Como texto siempre**

Answer (score 0):

¿Ha intentado ordenar en la segunda columna numérica (`-k 2n`) con un separador de campo específico (`-t ":"`)?

```bash
cat /etc/group | cut -d ":" -f 1,3 | sort -t ":" -k 2n
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero me los ordena de diferente manera pero no me muestra en el orden que yo quiero,me lo muestra de la siguiente manera:
[![Me muestra en el mismo orden como el ejemplo que he puesto arriba](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeitC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeitC.png) Lo que me interesaria que me muestre el guid primero y el nombre despues por ejemplo:
1:root gracias